# Sharing a file with data in it by UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to share a dictionary that has values with this structure:
some string values , videoData:Data, imageData:Base64 . I created it but UIActivityViewController couldn't share it.

```
 static func exportData(video:Video) -> URL{
    let videoData = try! Data(contentsOf: WebRequest.getDataPathwithFile(fileName: video.VideoID))
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: WebRequest.getDataPathwithFile(fileName: video.VideoID + ".jpg").path)
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1)?.base64EncodedString()

    let content:[String:Any] = ["title":video.Title,"id":video.VideoID,"duration":video.Duration,"viewcount":video.ViewCount,"data":videoData,"img":imageData]
    let saveFileURL = WebRequest.getDataPathwithFile(fileName: video.VideoID + ".bcd")
    (content as NSDictionary).write(to: saveFileURL, atomically: true)
    return saveFileURL

}
```

Am I doing correct? I want to share it by Airdrop and other users can get it,then the app on their iOS devices can recognize it and open it(I wrote the ImportData func before)

I am using Swift3 in Xcode 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who face this problem, this will works with this changed code:

```
let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: WebRequest.getDataPathwithFile(fileName: video.VideoID + ".jpg"))
```

You should get Data from Image directly via :

```
Data(contentsOf:)
```